# How did we find the solution?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In my lecture notes, I read that "We know that $$x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {7^3}$$ has as solution $$x \equiv 108 \pmod {7^3}$$"

How did we find this solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you only have 343 values to check, my best lazy guess would be exhaustive search. Not elegant, but fast with a computer.

Comment: @User, have you already studied Hensel's Lemma ?

Comment: @ClementC. Is this the only method to find the solution?

Comment: @Timbuc Not yet..

Comment: @user159870: most likely not... but whenever I see a statement of the form "we know that [...]" without a proof, I am almost always willing to bet on "we got that by a dumb but efficient way."

Comment: Do you even Hensel lift, bro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are small, so general techniques are not necessary. However, we describe, in this particular case, the method of **Hensel Lifting**.

It is clear that the solutions modulo $7$ are $x\equiv \pm 3\pmod{7}$. We *lift* the solution $x\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ to a solution of $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{7^2}$.

Any solution to $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{7^2}$ that is congruent to $3$ modulo $7$ has shape $x=3+7t$. Square. Modulo $7^2$, the result is congruent to $9+(2)(3)(7)t\pmod{7^2}$. We want this to be congruent to $2$ modulo $7^2$, so we want
$$9+(2)(3)(7)t\equiv 2\pmod{7^2}.$$
A little manipulation turns this to
$$(2)(3)t\equiv -1\pmod{7}.$$
Thus $t=1$ works, and we have
$$x\equiv 10\pmod{7^2}.$$
Now *lift* this solution to a solution of $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{7^3}$. We look for a solution of the shape $x\equiv 10+7^2t\pmod{7^3}$. 
Squaring, we get
$$100+(2)(10)(7^2)t\equiv 2\pmod{7^3},$$
which simplifies to 
$$(2)(10)t\equiv -2\pmod{7}.$$
A solution is $t\equiv 2\pmod{7}$. That gives solution $x\equiv 10+2(49)\pmod{7^3}$.

By general theory, the only solutions are therefore $x\equiv \pm 108\pmod{7^2}$.

**Remark:** If we wished to, we could continue, and lift to a solution modulo $7^4$, $7^5$, and so on.

Hensel lifting is an important general technique for solving polynomial congruences modulo prime powers.

Comment: Great answer, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that $108$ is one solution, you can exhaust the solution list as follows: noting $108^2=11664=2+34\times7^3$, you can write
$$
x^2\equiv 108^2 (\text{mod } 7^3)\implies7^3|(x-108)(x+108).
$$
Because $(x+108)-(x-108)=216$ is not divisible by $7$, we must either have $7^3|x-108$ or $7^3|x+108$. So you actually have **2** solutions: $x\equiv\pm 108(\text{mod }7^3$). These are all the solutions to $x^2\equiv 2(\text{mod }7^3)$.

Comment: beauty in its essence

Comment: Well it's kinda trivial you have two solutions. And I think your answer is really easy to see when you already know the solution to the congruence.

Comment: @ Harto: yes, this method requires that you know **one** solution.

Answer (score 0):

For example, $3^2=2\bmod 7$. So $(3+7k)^2=2+7+42k\bmod 7^2$. So $k=1$ and $10^2=2\bmod 7^2$. So $(10+7^2h)^2=2+2\cdot7^2(1+10h)\bmod 7^3$. So $h=2$. Bother! Is the crummy formatting my fault or the iPhone 6+ ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma) of Hensel's Lemma, which is basically the justification/proof of why what André did works, to go over the following:

$$x^2=2\pmod 7\iff f(x):=x^2-2=0\pmod 7\iff x=\pm 3\pmod 7$$

Choose now one of the roots, say $\;r=3\;$ , and let us "lift" it to a solution $\;\pmod{7^2}\;$ (check this is possible since $\;f'(3)=6\neq 0\pmod 7\;$)

$$s:=3+\left(-\frac77\cdot 6^{-1}\right)\cdot=3-(-1)^{-1}\cdot7=3+7=10$$

and indeed

$$f(10)=10^2-2=98=0\pmod{49=7^2}$$

Again:

$$s=10+\left(-\frac{98}7\cdot20^{-1}\right)\cdot7=10+14\cdot22\cdot7=2,166=108\pmod{7^3=343}$$

and indeed

$$f(108)=108^2-2=11,662=0\pmod{7^3}$$

Of course, you can repeat the above with every root in each stage.

Answer (score 0):

Without referring to Hensel I'd make the "Ansatz"
$$x=a\cdot 7^2+b\cdot7+c$$
with $|a|$, $|b|$, $|c|$ integers $\leq3$. This is no restriction of generality. The condition $x^2=2\ (7^3)$
leads to
$$(b^2+2ac)\cdot7^2+2bc\cdot7+ c^2-2=0\quad(7^3)\ .\tag{1}$$
It follows that $c^2=2\ (7)$, which implies $c=\pm3$. Plugging this into $(1)$ gives
$$(b^2\pm 6a)\cdot7^2 \pm 6b\cdot7+7=0\quad(7^3)\ ,$$
and dividing by $7$ leads to
$$(b^2\pm 6a)\cdot7+(\pm 6b+1)=0\quad(7^2)\ .\tag{2}$$
This implies $b=\pm1$. Inserting this into $(2)$ and dividing by $7$ again we obtain
$$(1\pm 6a)+1=0\quad(7)\ ,$$
and this is solved by $a=\pm2$.

Therefore all solutions of the original equation have to be of the form
$$x=\pm(2\cdot7^2+1\cdot7+3)=\pm 108\quad(7^3)\ .$$
It is easily checked that $\pm108$ indeed does the job.